# just nodejs / route working but another routes doesn't working on cpanel

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I created an API with node js express that works on localhost perfectly. but when I upload on the Cpanel just / route work and when I call another route that redirect to / route again

this is my server.js file

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const helmet = require("helmet");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid/async");
const cors = require("cors");

//middleware

//json body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//helmet
app.use(helmet());
app.use("/upload", express.static(process.cwd() + "/upload"));

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");
app.use("/user", userRoute);
const provinceRoute = require("./routes/provinceRoute");
app.use("/province", provinceRoute);
const adverbRoute = require("./routes/adverbRoute");
app.use("/adverb", adverbRoute);
const catSubRoute = require("./routes/catSubRoute");
app.use("/category", catSubRoute);
const uploadRoute = require("./routes/upload");
app.use("/upload", uploadRoute);

app.use('/',(req,resp)=>{
    resp.status(200).send("ok");
})

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("server is running...");
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is a route that I called with this URL

**https://example.com/api/category/getallcats**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const catSubController = require("../controllers/catSubController");

router.get("/getallcats", catSubController.getAllCats);

module.exports = router;
```

and this return ok the same
**https://example.com/api/** return ok on result